# Сохранение выбранных изображений

Tags: android

Приложение выводит картинки списком. Мне же нужно сделать так, чтобы выбранные из этого списка изображения сохранялись во внутренний каталог приложения. 
Было бы неплохо посмотреть на примеры кода..

Comment: посмотреть на цикл? Если для списка используется ListView, то с помощью метода getCheckedItemIds получаем список выделенных элементов. Дальше, циклом пробегаем по ним и сохраняем картинки. Соответствие id->картинка мы знаем.

Comment: Берите `File file=context.getFilesDir()` и пишите в этот файл все что вам придет в голову.

Comment: мне бы сам код посмотреть - как создается каталог и как туда сохраняются фотографии...

Comment: @Stas0n - ну извини, здесь не принято так. Здесь решают проблемы, но не пишут за других код.

Comment: @Barmaley, вообще то хотел просто , чтобы мне показали примеры, а не готовый код, которые решит все проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример записи bitmap на sd card: http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/saving-loading-bitmaps-to-the-android-device-storage-internal-external/

Вот еще пример на русском: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/138-urok-75-hranenie-dannyh-rabota-s-fajlami.html